# How To Change Value of Input Button after it loads up in DOM using jQuery

Tags: jquery, button, load

I have this telerik button with class name ruButton & ruBrowse, that loads up a little late into the DOM.
I am trying to change the Value of the button at page Load.

The Code below does not work at page load, but does work if attached to another button click event.

```
$(document).ready(
function(){
$(".ruButton.ruBrowse").attr('value', 'Browse');
}
);
```

My HTML DOM of the button looks like this.

```
<INPUT class="ruButton ruBrowse" value=Select type=button>
```

How do I get this to work at Page Load ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wrote: "I have this telerik button with class name ruButton & ruBrowse, that loads up a little late into the DOM".

If it loads late in the dom, the only surefire way to access it is to use its own supplied callback. If it doesn't have a supplied callback, you have to guess. You can load it on a timer like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $(".ruButton.ruBrowse").attr('value', 'Browse');
    }, 400);
});
```

[The above example it waits 400 milliseconds after dom load before trying to alter the button].

You also might want to consider using `$(window).load(...)` to wait for not just the dom, but the whole page to load.

But again, guessing is really hacky, will probably be wrong at least some of the time, and is certainly not good enough for production-quality code. If the library does not supply it's own callback, hack the library or use a different one.

Comment: Great this worked, however i just tweaked it to $(document).ready(function() {     setTimeout(function() {         $(".ruButton.ruBrowse").attr('value', 'Browse');     }, 1); });

Comment: @Nikil OK: That is the wrong approach; perhaps if you showed us your mark-up, how the button was loaded, we could determine _when_ and provide a more reliable solution - as it is, this presents a race condition and shouldn't be advocated (even suggested, IMO) at all.

Comment: Aha, the telerik library must be using the document.ready event too (via whatever platform, not jquery) to generate the buttons, but your callback happened first. By setting the timeout with 1 millisecond, you ensure that all document.ready events are finished before you try to alter the button. So this solution should be solid if my intuition about the library is correct.

Comment: @Mr. Disappointment, please see my previous comment. I do not think there is a risk for a race condition here. (Of course, you'd have to check the library itself to be sure).

Comment: Both of you presume execution of code scoped to the `ready` call used by Telerik will only take the amount of time _you_ specify - that isn't the case - it might take longer on any given cycle.

Comment: @MR.Disappointment ,Is there another way to solve the problem then ?

Comment: @Mr. Disappointment, no I'm not assuming that. It's in the way the javascript interpreter runs that functions called via setTimeout() are always called after anything in the current method. And if I understand the dom ready event correctly, all the callbacks are fired together as one method. In fact, I bet setting a timeout of zero would also work. "setTimeout(..., 0);". Really.

Comment: So, `setTimeout(..., 1000)` might potentially not be executed until an arbitrary amount of time later down the line (say, ten seconds?), when the enclosing scope finishes executing? I'm dubious, but uncertain, I must admit. What actually happens _within_ those callbacks is what would take the time, right? And this could be one second, or two minutes.

Comment: @Ben: Yes setting the setTimeout to 0 works aswell. Your right the previous call made tried to modify the button value even before it was available to the DOM. The setTimeOut does the trick ! That way I got to hack into the FileUpload telerik control's button, which by default only shows Select, and cant be renamed.

Comment: @Mr. Disappointment. Oh wait, I realize what I said is wrong. I was confusing it with something else (setTimeout of zero still runs asynchronously, duh). No, you are right.

Comment: I revert back to what I wrote originally: "But again, guessing is really hacky, will probably be wrong at least some of the time, and is certainly not good enough for production-quality code. If the library does not supply it's own callback, hack the library or use a different one."

Comment: @Nikil, please see the other solution I just posted. It is a little more robust.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly how 'late' is it loaded into to DOM? And how it is loaded?

This is a long shot, and even if it solves it, won't be the best solution, but:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).change(function() {
        $(".ruButton .ruBrowse").attr('value', 'Browse');
    });
});
```

EDIT:

Seeing that you updated your question, could you try the following...

Alter your mark-up, like so:

```
<input class="ruButton ruBrowse" value="Select" type="button">
```

I will assume the `button` type is a Telerik thing, and leave it as is.

Now, adjust your jQuery slightly (I noticed no space between the class names in the selector, which would seem to be an issue):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".ruButton .ruBrowse").attr('value', 'Browse');
});
```

Comment: There shouldn't be any space between the class names. A selector ".X.Y" (without a space) means "all elements with *both* classes X and Y". A selector ".X .Y" (with a space) means "an element with class Y who has a parent element with class X", which is completely wrong in this context. The lack-of-space was intentional.

Comment: Also, I still think this isn't going to work. Web browsers are smart enough to interpret the HTML without quotes. I'm pretty sure it's just the telerik library running it's own dom.ready stuff, and a 1ms timeout is a race-proof method if that's the case.

Comment: @Ben Lee: Interesting facts about the selectors, thanks for sharing. I know you have conceded to the fact that the timeout method isn't _race-proof_, so will ignore that comment. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I just thought of another solution, one that is solid even if you don't know how long it will take for the buttons to load (turns out the 1-millisecond timer that worked for you probably really was just a guess). You just have to run a timer over and over to check if they are all loaded, like so:

```
var wait_for_telerik_buttons = function() {
    if ($("input[type='button']").length === $('ruButton.ruBrowse').length) {
        $(".ruButton.ruBrowse").attr('value', 'Browse');
    } else {
        setTimeout(wait_for_telerik_buttons, 100);
    }
};
setTimeout(wait_for_telerik_buttons, 20);
```

Can't say it's the most efficient method, but if your first guess is good (20 milliseconds in the example above) then it will usually catch it the first time around. But there is a 100-ms timer loop in case the guess was bad in any particular instance. Race condition solved.

Answer (score 0):

Telerik File Upload Button Value can be changed by using Telerik's localization support itself.
I had to use javascript to hack in before I was aware of this.

```
<telerik:RadUpload ID="RadUpload" runat="server" TargetFolder="..\..\Upload" MaxFileInputsCount="1">
                 <Localization Select="Browse" />
            </telerik:RadUpload>
```

The Locatlization Select = Browse does the job the right way. Had this option not been available the Javascript work arounds help.

Answer (score -2):

You can also use this

`$(document).ready(
   $(".ruButton.ruBrowse").val('Browse');
);`

Comment: Please try once at your end before posting to this site